# Why http.Request does not implement io.Reader interface?

Tags: go

Below concrete type `http.Request`:

```
type Request struct {

    Method string

    URL *url.URL


    Header Header

    Body io.ReadCloser
    .....
}
```

---

has `Body io.ReadCloser` implementing `io.Reader` type but `Header Header` does not implement `io.Reader` interface

---

My understanding is, `http.Request` should implement `io.Reader` interface.

---

Why `http.Request` does not implement `io.Reader` interface? to facilitate reading both header and body of an http request.

Answer (score 2):

Use [http.ReadRequest](https://godoc.org/net/http#ReadRequest) to read a request from a stream of bytes.

The [Request](https://godoc.org/net/http#Request) type does not implement [io.Reader](https://godoc.org/io#Reader) because a [Request](https://godoc.org/net/http#Request) does not represent a stream of bytes.

Comment: Any reason, why `http.Request` does not implement `io.Reader`?

Comment: `r.Body` is stream of bytes, because we are able to `json.NewDecoder(r).Decode(productItem)`